# Redireccionar URL terminada con varias barras a la misma URL con una sola barra

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Resulta hice un redireccionamiento a mi web para que redireccionara la url sin barra a la url con barra siempre y cuando no fuera un archivo.

```
# si no existe un archivo que coincida con la solicitud...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# y si no termina con una barra, redireccionar a la misma dirección pero con la barra
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]$) $1/ [R,QSA,L]
```

Lo encontré en esta misma página, pero ahora quiero que si se intenta acceder a la url con varias barras, también redireccione a la misma url con una sola barra.

Ejemplo:

```
www.mipagina.com/categoria/articulo-numero-201////
```

redireccione a

```
www.mipagina.com/categoria/articulo-numero-201/
```

Comment: Ese regex creo haberlo visto antes. Al referenciar código de [es.so], por favor mantené el crédito del autor agregando el enlace a la respuesta de donde lo hayas sacado.

Answer (score 2):

Uno podría pensar que se haría con un `RewriteRule` que coincida con `//`. Sin embargo, Apache elimina las barras redundantes al pasarlas al .htaccess. Por eso, tenemos que comparar a `%{REQUEST_URI}` (que tiene la solicitud original).

```py
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redireccionar si tiene 2 o más "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //
# a la URL sin barras redundantes (Apache las elimina)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/*$ $1/ [R=301,L]


# si no existe un archivo que coincida con la solicitud...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# y si no termina con una barra, redireccionar a la misma dirección pero con la barra
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ $0/ [R=301,L]
```

---

Demos (que subí a un hosting gratuito):

- http://mariano.uphero.com/153315/sin-barra
- http://mariano.uphero.com/153315/demasiadas////////////////////

Comment: Muchas gracias esa es la forma para redireccionar varias barras a una sola lo pude hacer en una pagina que administro y quedo excelente.

Comment: @AndrewHerrera me alegro que te sirviera. Tené en cuenta que podés aceptar la respuesta haciendo click en el ✔️ debajo de las flechas de votación